# How to count the total number of nodes in binary tree

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, binary-tree, nodes

I need to count the total number of nodes in binary tree. The problem now arise when I execute this code, it's giving garbage value for total number of nodes. The output of my program is like `993814`. which should be `7`.

How to fix this problem?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct binarytree
{
    int data;
    struct binarytree * right, * left;
};

typedef struct binarytree node;

void insert(node ** tree, int val)
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = val;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }

    if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->left, val);
    }
    else if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->right, val);
    }

}

void print_preorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        printf("%d\n",tree->data);
        print_preorder(tree->left);
        print_preorder(tree->right);
    }

}

void print_inorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        print_inorder(tree->left);
        printf("%d\n",tree->data);
        print_inorder(tree->right);
    }
}

int count(node *tree)
{
    int c=0;

    if (tree ==NULL)
        return 0;

    else
    {
        c += count(tree->left);
        c += count(tree->right);
        return c;
    }
}

void print_postorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        print_postorder(tree->left);
        print_postorder(tree->right);
        printf("%d\n",tree->data);
    }
}

int main()
{
    node *root;
    node *tmp;
    int c;

    root = NULL;
    /* Inserting nodes into tree */
    insert(&root, 9);
    insert(&root, 10);
    insert(&root, 15);
    insert(&root, 6);
    insert(&root, 12);
    insert(&root, 17);
    insert(&root, 2);

    /* Printing nodes of tree */
    printf("Pre Order Display\n");
    print_preorder(root);

    printf("In Order Display\n");
    print_inorder(root);

    printf("Post Order Display\n");
    print_postorder(root);

    printf("Number of node %d \n",c);

}
```

Comment: It's easiest if you keep track of an internal count by incrementing in insert() and decrementing on remove().

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You declare `c` but not initialize nowhere and also not used in anywhere.
Then you print the value of `c`, which gives you garbage value.

You can fix your `count(node *tree)` function as

```
int count(node *tree)
{
    int c =  1;             //Node itself should be counted
    if (tree ==NULL)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        c += count(tree->left);
        c += count(tree->right);
        return c;
    }
}
```

add in `main`

```
int main()
{
    .............
    .............


    c = count(root);        //number of node assign to c
    printf("Number of node %d \n",c);
}
```

Comment: `  int count(node *tree)
    {
        int c=0;

        if (tree ==NULL)
           return 0;

        else
        {
        c += count(tree->left);
        c += count(tree->right);
        return c;
        }
    }` here I used.

Comment: Here `int c=0` is the local variable of `count(node *tree)` function, and also you doesn't call it from  `main`.

Comment: okey,Can you please tell me,how to call that c to main method?

Comment: @acer, is it fix your problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,Thank you so much,your answer is working fine.

Answer (score 21):

I would rather do it by returning the sum in each recursive call without using the local variable.

```
int count(struct node *root){
    if(root == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 1 + count(root->left) + count(root->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach as it makes the function more intuitive.

Comment: what would be the time complexity of this in the worst-case?

Comment: @Melvin86 It will always be O(N) where N is the number of nodes

Answer (score 0):

`count` function would be

```
int count(struct node *root)
{
    int a=1;

    if (root==NULL){
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        a += count(root->left);
        a += count(root->right);
        return a;
    }
}
```

In the main function, the calling of `count` function would be like that

```
printf("total no of nodes  of binary tree is %d\n",count(p));//p is root node
```